# selenium webdriver invalid login

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

i want  to close the browser for an invalid username/password but i am not able to do that. It runs well for a valid input though but for an invalid one it just freezes in the page where it shows "invalid login". this is my code. setup1 is just opening the browser.

while(recordset.next()){

```
                   setUp1();
                   System.out.println(driver1);
                  driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);       

               System.out.println(recordset.getField("NAME"));
               System.out.println(recordset.getField("PASSWORD"));

               String store1 = recordset.getField("NAME");
               String store = recordset.getField("PASSWORD");


                driver1.findElement(By.id("signin_button")).click();
                driver1.findElement(By.id("user_login")).clear();
                driver1.findElement(By.id("user_password")).clear();
                driver1.findElement(By.id("user_login")).sendKeys(store1);
                driver1.findElement(By.id("user_password")).sendKeys(store);

                driver1.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();


                driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//div/ul[@class = 'nav float-right']/li[3]")).click();            
                driver1.findElement(By.id("logout_link")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `driver1.close()` if  `driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//div/ul[@class = 'nav float-right']/li[3]"))` throws a `NoSuchElementException`  exception.

The browser will be closed if the current page is the only open page in the browser.

Here is an example:

```
try{
    WebElement elm = driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//div/ul[@class = 'nav float-right']/li[3]"));
    elm.click();
}catch(NoSuchElementException e){
    driver1.close();
    break; // exit the loop.
}
```

Comment: no its not working. i need something which will close the browser when there is an invalid login. its not closing.

Comment: @AvantikaSarkar Instead of `By.xpath("//div/ul[@class = 'nav float-right']/li[3]")` try to get an element that is shown only on valid login or check for an element that only shows on invalid login and if it is present, call `close()`.

Comment: ya i m trying to add the error element using if else but i m not able to do that. its showing add "!=null".

Comment: @AvantikaSarkar The `findElement(...)` method throws a `NoSuchElementException` if the element doesn't exist. Instead of checking if the "error element" is not `null` you should check if when you try to find this element, no exception is thrown.